# remaining 20.04 packages after release upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I performed a `do-release-upgrade` from 20.04 to 22.04 LTS on two machines. Both went through.

Now I see different old packages on them:

`apt list --installed | grep 20.04`

```
g++-11/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
gcc-11-base/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
gcc-11/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
gcc-13-base/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
gcc-13-base/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 i386 [installed,local]
libasan6/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libatomic1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libatomic1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 i386 [installed,local]
libcc1-0/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libgcc-11-dev/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libgcc-s1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libgcc-s1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 i386 [installed,local]
libgcc1/now 1:13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libgomp1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libitm1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
liblsan0/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libmbim-glib4/jammy-updates,now 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmbim-proxy/jammy-updates,now 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libquadmath0/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libstdc++-11-dev/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libstdc++6/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
libstdc++6/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 i386 [installed,local]
libtsan0/now 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libubsan1/now 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/jammy-updates,now 5.15.0.83.80 amd64 [installed]
```

the other machine has far less:

```
libmbim-glib4/jammy-updates,now 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libmbim-proxy/jammy-updates,now 1.28.0-1~ubuntu20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/now 5.15.0.82.91~20.04.40 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/now 5.15.0.82.91~20.04.40 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04/now 5.15.0.82.91~20.04.40 amd64 [installed,local]
```

1. Is this a problem? I tried to install rstudio and it works on the second machine, but fails on the first due to incompatibilities : `sudo apt install -f ./rstudio-2023.06.2-561-amd64.deb` gives

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libobjc-11-dev : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgcc-11-dev (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I guess it is a problem at least for the first machine.

2. How can I fix this? Maybe some old packages can simply be deleted (e.g. unused linux header etc) but how to upgrade gcc etc to 22.04?

Comment: Looks like your first machine perhaps had an failed/partial/incomplete release-upgrade. Had the release-upgrade completed properly, the older packages would have already been replaced by newer. Review your apt log for the release-upgrade, and look for error messages.

Comment: Thanks. It went trough and only reported an issue with the nvidia driver: 

INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new

ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'nvidia-driver-470': 'dependency problems - leaving unconfigured'

But I think this is not the root of the problem, which rather is the fact that all the gcc stuff is listed as "Foreign" and therefore not touched during upgrade. How can I manually remove these packages and re-install the correct ones? They seem to have lots of dependencies.

Comment: could not get those packages replaced with the correct ones. Also removing did not work as important system package depend on them. So I ended up re-installing the OS from scratch. Would be great if someone knows how to i) replace those packages in such a situation, or ii) knows a way to prevent the issue in the first place (e.g. replace the local packages before the dist upgrade). Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)